# Swift Repeat Interval

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol, intervals

I have an app I'm working on with a `UISegmentedControl` to allow the user to select a repeat interval for the notification they are creating.  
They also pick the date and time to start, by selecting it on the `UIDatePicker`.

```
//Variables for Repeat (SegmentedControl)
var hourly = true
var daily = true

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var deadlinePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var repeatPreseto: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButtonOutlet: UIButton!

//Repeat Segmented Control
@IBAction func repeatPreset(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    var index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    hourly = index == 0
    daily = index == 2
    if hourly {
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour
    }
    if daily {
       notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
    }
}
```

Right now the hourly and daily repeatInterval is working great.

I've looked online and can't find anything to allow for the user to set the repeatInterval for certain days of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that one of the old interval methods was depreciate in iOS 8.0.  I found I need to use:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfMonth
```